# Creating a dimension with a range

Tags: python, range, netcdf

I'm trying to create a netCDF file from a large dataset. I want this new file to hold Temperature and Time.

My time is a range and this is causing problems when I try to create my dimensions. I keep getting this error:

> Cannot find dimension timerange in this group or parent groups

```
filehandle = Dataset(path+indices,'r',format="NETCDF4")
lat = 0
lon = 0
timerange = range(0, 1459)

temps = get_var(filehandle, 'tair')[timerange, lat, lon]

ncfile = Dataset(ncname,'w')
times = ncfile.createDimension('time', timerange)
temp_out = ncfile.createVariable('temps', 'f4', ('times'))
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dimension, You have give the size of the dimension or None for unlimited dimension. This should work:

```
times = ncfile.createDimension('time', len(timerange))
```